# How can I make a field in Django models that concatenates a specific string to each record's id?

Tags: python, django, django-models, concatenation

I have made a field `facility_id` in Django models that should concatenate a specific string `"ACCTS-"` on the left with each record's `id` on the right,

My model class is below:

```
class Facility(models.Model):
    ...
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    facility_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=print(f'{"ACCTS-"}{id}'), editable=False)
    ...
```

I want to the `facility_id` field to be storing special and readable human friendly facility_id's of the form: `ACCTS-1`, `ACCTS-2`, `ACCTS-3`, ... corresponding to each individual `id`.

The migrations didn't throw any errors, however When I try to create the records for this table in the Django Admin, am getting an `IntegrityError` of:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/ACCTS_CLYCAS/facility/add/
NOT NULL constraint failed: ACCTS_CLYCAS_facility.facility_id
```

How do I fix this problem, or what could be the easiest way to implement my problem.

Comment: Why work with a field in the first place, if it is always `ACCTS-id`, then you can make it a property, or the `__str__` method of your `Facility` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The migrations didn't throw any errors, however When I try to create the records for this table in the Django Admin

That makes sense, since you have set the `default=None`. Indeed, `print(…)` returns `None` and only prints the value to the standard output channel (stdout). It will thus not prepend the value of the `id` with `ACCTS`.

If the `facility_id`s are all just the id prefixed with `ACCTS-`, you can work with a `@property` instead:

```
class Facility(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    
    @property
    def facility_id(self):
        return f'ACCTS-{self.id}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using a post save signal.

Add blank = True to facility_id and then use a post save signal to update the value of facility_id.

You can watch this tutorial on how to use [Django Signals](https://youtu.be/W8MLlwvSS-U)

Comment: Please don't. If you do this you will have to save the object again, using *two* queries, furthermore you will need a check to prevent infinite recursion, and Django signals can be circumvented: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html#why-is-it-a-problem

Comment: Oh! I was not aware of it, Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Why is this link in the answer, it is more efficient to add a small sample code in your answer.